# Did any contestant ever win the final round on the Africa map of Where in the World is Carmen Sandiego?

Tags: carmen-sandiego

The online web series *[The Game Show Reviewer](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXlbxN92THx_sAW11Euk6chkIMM-jr574&app=desktop)* had an episode about the PBS game show *[Where in the World is Carmen Sandiego?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_in_the_World_Is_Carmen_Sandiego%3F_%28game_show%29)* and its sister show *[Where in Time is Carmen Sandiego?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_in_Time_Is_Carmen_Sandiego%3F_(game_show))*. In it, he says the following about the final round of the former show where contestants need to place markers on a map of a continent (video at time stamp and transcript below):

> Take note what I said however: that the *objective* of the round is simple. The round itself is basically an endurance round, and if you ever ended up on the Africa map, yeah you may as well say you lose right there. Honestly, I don't remember seeing *anyone* ever winning on this map. But then again, not even I've seen every episode of this series.

Has any contestant ever won on the Africa map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, several contestants got through it according to [this](http://www.sbnation.com/2013/4/4/4174436/carmen-sandiego-africa-map), though they needed every single second, usually. Here's a documented instance, from episode 4 in season 1 (with 7 locations identified):

And here's another instance from episode 8 in season 2, with 8 locations (starts around 3:30):